# Use XML serialization to serialize a collection without the parent node

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Let's say I have a class;

```
public class Car 
{ 
  public List<Passenger> Passengers {get; set;} 
}
```

I want to serialize this to XML such that Passengers are child nodes of Car and there is no intervening Passengers node. In other words I want the output to look like this;

```
<Car>
  <Passenger>...</Passenger>
  <Passenger>...</Passenger>
</Car>
```

and not like this, which is the default layout;

```
<Car>   
  <Passengers>
    <Passenger>...</Passenger>
    <Passenger>...</Passenger>
  </Passengers> 
</Car>
```

There's an attribute I need to add to Car.Passengers to achieve this, I don't recall which though.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is what I was after!

> ```
> [XmlElement("Passenger")]
> public List<Passenger> Passengers {get; set;}
> ```

Comment: What? :) That changes nothing except removing the entire entry. How do you get the childs serialilzed if the parent is not marked as [datamember]   ?