# XML Deserialization getting rid of need to create a collection wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I was reading about [XML Serialization on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx).

In the examples you can see there is actually a class called `Group` that is like a wrapper for a collection. Because there can be multiple `Group`s.

```
public class Group{
    public Employee[] Employees;
}
public class Employee{
    public string Name;
}
```

In my case the XML might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Company>
    <Employees>
        <Employee .../>
        <Employee .../>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Employee .../>
        <Employee .../>
    </Employees>
</Company>
```

I don't want to create a a `class Employees { public Employee[] Employees; }`. **It is better** to have `Employee[][]`  instead of creating a separate `Employees` class to sit inside `Company` class.

Is there a way to achieve this with `XmlSerializer` of .NET framework?

Comment: I suppose "better" is a bit subjective. My "better" is to have a completely separate data serialization layer that converts to/from my business objects (of which the rest of my application works with). So in my serialization layer I can have a variety of wrapper collections, or whatever that allows for simple, flexible, and readable semantics that meshes well with the XML schema. Or if my XML schema changes (or I use a completely different serializer later, like JSON or protobuf-net) then the core/meat-and-potatoes of my application doesn't care.

Comment: Seems that the XmlSerializer doesn't support jagged arrays, so I'm not sure if there's a solution short of having your own collection wrapper (which is what you were trying to avoid in the first place): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135445/c-sharp-xml-serialization-remove-jagged-array-element-name

Comment: Seems that you need a custom xml serializer, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx)