# C# Deserializing an XML with repeating tags

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, deserialization

I have an input XML string with repeating `<row>` tags that I'm trying to deserialize into an object, but all the rows except the last one get ignored. Any help would be appreciated.

As an example, after the deserialization, the object I get is:

```
object.command[0].userTable =
    {OCI.OCITable}
        colHeading: {string[3]}
        colHeadingField: {string[3]}
        row: {string[3]}
        rowField: {string[3]}
```

This is wrong, because there is only one row in this object, but there should be 4 `<row>` in the input XML string like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
  <BroadsoftDocument protocol="OCI" xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <sessionId xmlns="">feajiofefeaij</sessionId> 
  <command echo="" xsi:type="UserGetListInServiceProviderResponse" xmlns="">
  <userTable>
      <colHeading>User Id</colHeading> 
      <colHeading>Group Id</colHeading> 
      <colHeading>Name</colHeading>
      <row>
          <col>1</col> 
          <col>A</col> 
          <col>Smith</col> 
      </row>
      <row>
          <col>2</col> 
          <col>A</col> 
          <col>John</col> 
      </row>
      <row>
          <col>3</col> 
          <col>B</col> 
          <col>James</col> 
      </row>
      <row>
          <col>4</col> 
          <col>B</col> 
          <col>Lisa</col> 
      </row>
  </userTable>
  </command>
  </BroadsoftDocument>
```

The way I'm doing deserialization is:

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString));
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OCIMessage));
OCIMessage response = (OCIMessage)ser.Deserialize(memStream);
```

And the C# class automatically generated by `xsd.exe` for the `OCITable` class is this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "C")]
public partial class OCITable
{

    private string[] colHeadingField;
    private string[] rowField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("colHeading", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string[] colHeading
    {
        get
        {
            return this.colHeadingField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.colHeadingField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("col", typeof(string), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] row
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rowField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.rowField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For row and col change from XmlArrayItemAttribute (all places) to XmlElement.

Comment: @jdweng could you explain what the difference is?

Comment: XmlArray creates a 2nd tag like <rows><row> while XElement only creates <row>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that, in your XML, the `<row>` and `<col>` elements are a 2d jagged array: there is an outer, repeating set of `<row>` elements containing an inner, repeating set of `<col>` elements, each of which has a string value.  But in your `OCITable` class you have modeled this as a 1d array of strings:

```
public string[] row { get; set; }
```

This only allows for *one* outer `<row>` element.  If multiple `<row>` elements are encountered while parsing, `XmlSerializer` will overwrite the earlier values with the later - which is exactly what you are seeing.

In order to capture the nested hierarchy of row and column elements, you would instead need to do something like:

```
public string[][] row { get; set; }
```

However, if you do, you will encounter the problem described in [C# xml serialization remove jagged array element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135445/c-sharp-xml-serialization-remove-jagged-array-element-name), namely that `XmlSerializer` will always serialize a 2d jagged array with an extra outer container element, like so:

```
<row>
    <col>
        <string>a</string>
    </col>
    <col>
        <string>b</string>
    </col>
</row>
```

Thus this also will not work.

Instead, you will need to make your `row` member a simple array of intermediate classes which contain a 1d array of strings, like so:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "C")]
public partial class OCITable
{
    private string[] colHeadingField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("colHeading", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string[] colHeading
    {
        get
        {
            return this.colHeadingField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.colHeadingField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public OCITableRow [] row { get; set; }
}

public class OCITableRow
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("col", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] col { get; set; }
}
```

Both the `row` and `col` arrays are marked with [`[XmlElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) to indicate they should be serialized as a repeating sequence of elements without an outer container element.

With the classes defined above you will be able to deserialize your `<userTable>` element.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dcxcgH).

Comment: I'm curious, is it normal to need to tweak the C# classes after generating them from XSD Schemas? I generated those classes with xsd.exe that came with Visual Studio using the schemas provided by the webservice. Do you think the cause of this issue is incomplete Schemas, or I didn't configure the class generator properly, or if it is common to need to tweak the classes by hand after generation? (To be fair, the generated code did have `string[][] ` but I changed it to 1D array because 2D array was crashing my app)

Comment: @Synia - usually it's not necessary.  Maybe xsd.exe has a problem with jagged arrays without container elements similar to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135445/c-sharp-xml-serialization-remove-jagged-array-element-name)?

Comment: Synia - have to love BroadSoft/BroadWorks and Java! We just ran into the same issue and were headed down this same route based on other articles, @dbc thanks for the working example!