# XmlElement Attribute being ignored by Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-serialization

I'm returning an object as xml in a asp.net 5 controller. The object has an property that is a list and I need the serializer to ignore the root element of the list. I've followed this post's suggestion [Use XML serialization to serialize a collection without the parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639471/use-xml-serialization-to-serialize-a-collection-without-the-parent-node) but for some reason it doesn't work it even ignores if a I try to change the name of it using [XmlElement("newName")]

Any clues why it might be doing that?

```
public partial class Doc {

    [XmlElement("Detalle")]
    public List<DefTypeDetalle> Detalle { get; set; }

}

public partial class DefTypeDetalle {

    public Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the output I get

```
<Doc>
    <Detalle>
        <DefTypeDetalle>
            <Id>1<Id/>
        </DefTypeDetalle>
        <DefTypeDetalle>
            <Id>2<Id/>
        </DefTypeDetalle>
    </Detalle>
</Doc>
```

And what I want is

```
<Doc>   
    <Detalle>
        <Id>1<Id/>
    </Detalle>
    <Detalle>
        <Id>2<Id/>
    </Detalle>  
</Doc>
```

thanks

Comment: Can I see the code in question?

Comment: OK, I've added the code and xml too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was the formatter that I was using, I had in Startup.cs

```
 mvcBuilder.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

and needed to use the xml serializer

```
mvcBuilder.AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the way you're serializing the data. Try

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DefTypeDetalle>));
    using ( TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter( @"your_directory")
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, your_list) 
    }
```

Comment: It's an MVC project so I'm not manually serializing, the controller outputs xml because  I ask for it in the headers of the request

Comment: Is the result different if you use only [XmlElement] without the name specification? What happens if you change from List<T> to array?

Comment: It's the same output without the attribute and I had it as an array before :(

Comment: The output stream service consuming your entity data might not be aware of the XmlElementAttribute type. Is it possible to develop an alternative implementation?

Comment: I suppose, I was aiming to have clean controllers, but I may have to extend the serializer

Comment: From everything I've read about the issue, you are coding your XmlElementAttribute properly. There must be a framework issue, and those are never known for their cleanliness..